# form php submission gives same style

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm creating a page with a PHP form, and it works well. But the problem is when I hit the checl button check it gives answers in the white page, not in the same html tabl.

I want it to gives the submission in the same table style , as well as add a new button to the form that shows answers without taking the exercise.

And this is an example, showing want I'm trying to do:

http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/exercises/questions/simple_present.htm

```
<?php
   $correctSolution1 = 'do';
   $correctSolution2 = 'do';
   if(isset($_POST['add']) == TRUE) {
       $solution1 = $_POST['solution1'];
       if(empty($solution1) == TRUE) {
           echo '<span style="color: blue;">"unanswered"</span> you like lemon?</br>';
       } else if ($solution1 == $correctSolution1) {
           echo '<span style="color: green;">'.$solution1.'</span> you like lemon?</br>';
       } else {
           echo '<span style="color: red;">'.$solution1.'</span> you like lemon?</br>';
       }

       $solution2 = $_POST['solution2'];
       if ( empty($solution2) == TRUE ) {
           echo '<span style="color: blue;">"_____"</span> you like lemon? <img src="http://www.pavendors.com/images/smileyface.gif" width="16px" height="16px" border=0></br>';
       } else if ( $solution2 == $correctSolution2 ) {
           echo '<span style="color: green;">'.$solution2.'</span> you like lemon?</br>';
       } else {
           echo '<span style="color: red;">'.$solution2.'</span> you like lemon?</br>';
       }
       echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '"><input type="button"  value="Repeat test" /></a>';
    } else {
?>
    <form  method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <table align=center width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
         <td>
          <table align=left width="100%" bgcolor="#FFCC99" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
            <tr>
              <td>
              <table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="1">
                <tr></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td>
               <table>                                                <tr><td  colspan="2">1) <input type="text"  name="solution1" value="" size="6" /> you      <input type="text" class="ex_textfield" id="1" tabindex="1" name="solution2" value="" size="6" /> mineral water? <b><i>(to drink)</i></b></td></tr>                       
                       </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr><td height="1"><hr></td></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left"><input class="small_button" type="submit" name="add" value="Check" />
                <br>
                <hr> </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</form>
          <?php
            }
           ?>
```

Comment: You should rephrase your question. There is no way on earth to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: ok sure i will rephrase it now

Comment: i think ajax is what you want

Comment: i don't know but i don't prefer javascript same of that website i afford it doesn't use javascript in its form

Comment: is it hard this much? any help i really need it

Answer (score 0):

You should look in to embeeding php inside html:
In example above you are doing :

```
<?php
   $correctSolution1 = 'do';
   $correctSolution2 = 'do';
   if(isset($_POST['add']) == TRUE) {

   }
   else{?>
<form>
<table></table>
</form>
<?php }?>
```

So you code here does not go to form and table part when you do a submit(post request) through from. 
You can either add table part to the post if statement part as well like below:

```
<?php
       $correctSolution1 = 'do';
       $correctSolution2 = 'do';
       if(isset($_POST['add']) == TRUE) {
    //do your php stuffs here
?>
<table>
...
your html you can include values in to it like this <?php echo $solution2;?>
...
</table>
<?php
}
else{?>
<form>
  <table></table>
</form>
<?php }?>
```

OR you can do this as well:

```
<?php 
  //php part here may be some variable assignments
  $correctSolution1 = 'do';
  correctSolution2 = 'do';
?>

<form>
<table>
....
<?php if(isset($_POST['add']) == TRUE) {?>
 your other code here for result
<?php }?>
....
</table>
</form>
```

So basically you will need to understand properly about embedding php in to html.
You may look in to alternative syntax in php for statements like if, while, for, switch;
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php
you can do things like:

```
<?php if(true):?>
//if code here
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: right friend, i embeded the code inside table but the issue when i submit the form of input fields do go they stay with results ? any suggestion ? and what about the button functions showing results directly without answer the questions